# Mongodb and nodejs geonear response changes location?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On my nodejs app, i query mongodb to output users 100km around of an given address.

Below is a document type :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b26192e01e60e1e67e37b50"), 
    "loc":[2.4066412, 48.8599825]
    ....
}
```

And the nodejs query :

```
const distance = "100000";
User.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ latitude, longitude ]},
        distanceField: "loc",
        minDistance:0,
        maxDistance:distance,
        spherical: true
    }
}], function(err, resp){
    console.log(resp)
})
```

This code works well, i can output users around specified distance, but the response object location has changed :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b26192e01e60e1e67e37b50"), 
    "loc": "5419.825102233618" // <=== WHY IT DOESN'T RETURN RIGHT DATA ?
    ....
}
```

Someone could explain me why this change from response data? the expected output is not :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b26192e01e60e1e67e37b50"), 
    "loc": "5419.825102233618"
    ....
}
```

but :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b26192e01e60e1e67e37b50"), 
    "loc":[2.4066412, 48.8599825]
    ....
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) works on geospatial indexes not on fields directly and I guess this is why it might be confusing. It means that before you run `$geoNear` you have to create an index like this:

```
db.col.ensureIndex({ loc: "2dsphere" })
```

And that's the only place where you specify `loc` as an input for `$geoNear`. Then when you use `distanceField: "loc"` you define that you'd like to get calculated distance in `loc` field which simply overrides your coordinates.

So to get both distance and coordinates from source document you should define distance field as a different key, for instance:

```
db.col.aggregate([{
    $geoNear: {
        near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [2.4066412, 48.8599825]},
        distanceField: "distance",
        minDistance:0,
        maxDistance: 10000,
        spherical: true
    }
}])
```

Then you'll get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b26192e01e60e1e67e37b50"), "loc" : [ 2.4066412, 48.8599825 ], "distance" : 0 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, more clean for me, i will give a try

Comment: Hi, i just tried your advice and works with success. thank you.